# Find specified string in nested lists with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, nested-lists

I have a class Node

```
 public class Node
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
    }
```

The nested level is four levels. What I want to achieve is to find specified in function below string in any of nested lists. Here is a function:

```
public string getNumber(List<Node> currentList, string name)
    {
        string number = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in currentList)
        {
            if (item.Header == name)
            {
                number = item.Number;
                return number;
            }
        }
        if (number == string.Empty)
        {
            foreach (var item in currentList)
            {
                number = getNumber(item.Nodes, name);
                return number;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It's iterating through first nested list from first item in list, but not for the rest items nested lists. Can anyone give me a hint where is my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the recursion here... maybe you ment to call `getNumber` again instead of `getNumberFromName` ?

Comment: my bad, should be getNumber instead, but anyway it doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the recursive call found a number with a null check, otherwise you only check the sub list of the first item. Also you don't need to initialize `number` to empty or check it after the first `foreach` since you would have already returned if you found a match.  And if you do find a match in the initial list you don't even need to set it to `number`, so you don't even need that variable until your second `foreach`.

```
public string getNumber(List<Node> currentList, string name)
{
    foreach (var item in currentList)
    {
        if (item.Header == name)
        {
            return item.Number;
        }
    }

   foreach (var item in currentList)
   {
       string number = getNumber(item.Nodes, name);
       if (number != null)
       {
           return number;
       }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Also you might want to think about the order you want to search stuff.  Currently this will do a search in the following order

> -1
>
> --3
>
> ---5
>
> ---6
>
> --4
>
> ---7
>
> -2
>
> --8

Where number of dashes represent the depth.

Comment: Great, thanks. Now it's working as expected :)